# How can my database support multiple users?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, multiple-users

I have a question and hopefully not look dumb. I am developing an application and I need the database Web service multiple users store data so that later they can access their data on specific data without mixing with other users.

I thought that the solution might be to increase each of my tables the userid attribute is foreign key to the user table. However, I wonder if there is a better solution to this something that requires change all tables.

I appreciate any help !!!!

Comment: The solution is to have a user table and relate the userid to each of the individuals data. This is very simple in sql and the database should be designed before you start the app.

Comment: With PostgreSQL schemes working fine

Answer (score 0):

First of all we should have  a UML picture to understand what is "data" and what it means. As a blind man in the darkness i can advise you that:

you should have a table with users, and a table with data with userId as a foreign key to the relevant data.

Comment: Now i use apartment gem for ruby on rails applications. However Thanks